# Why do I still receive warning for possible NPE in IntelliJ when I do my null checking?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, lint, intellij-15

I have a function that could return a null value. So I used JetBrains annotation and put a `@Nullable` annotation on top of the function.

```
@Nullable
public static ConnectionManager getConnectionManager() {
    return connectionManager;
}
```

Then, I runned a Lint inspection. I found 4 places when I use this function and I wasn't doing any null check.

Before:

```
Service.getConnectionManager().onAssetInfoChanged();
```

After:

```
if(Service.getConnectionManager() != null) {
    Service.getConnectionManager().onAssetInfoChanged();
}
```

Then I run the Lint inspection again. To my big surprise, I'm still getting:

> Method invocation '`Service.getConnectionManager().onAssetInfoChanged()`' at line 308 may produce '`java.lang.NullPointerException`'.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug in the Lint inspector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inspector is not completely wrong. It is possible that you could have a `NullPointerException` in this case: since you are calling `Service.getConnectionManager()` each time, there's no way we can be absolutely sure that it won't return `null` the second time even though it did not the first time: the getter could have a more complicated logic than `return ...` or the variable may have been set to `null` concurrently between the two method calls.

As such, you could refactor your code to:

```
ConnectionManager manager = Service.getConnectionManager();
if (manager != null) {
    manager.onAssetInfoChanged();
}
```

assuming that the return type of `getConnectionManager()` is an object of type `ConnectionManager`. With this, it is impossible to have a `NullPointerException` on that line.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're calling `Service.getConnectionManager()` twice.  On the second invocation when you actually use it Lint has to make the assumption it could now be null.  One way to solve this is to use a local variable like this:

```
ConnectionManager connectionManager = Service.getConnectionManager();
if(connectionManager != null) {
    connectionManager.onAssetInfoChanged();
}
```

An alternative, and in my opinion preferred approach would be to avoid the null in the first place.  If you're using Java 8 you can use an `Optional` to represent the fact your `ConnectionManager` can be null.

The best approach would be to ensure your `ConnectionManager` is actually never `null`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `@Nullable` is related to method parameters that can be null. The opposite is `NotNull` which means that the parameter must be set. And secondly, each call of `getConnectionManager` is treated by the analyzer separately. Do it like this

```
ConnectionManager connManager = Service.getConnectionManager();
if(connManager != null
{
//do your stuff
}
```